# Probability that a point picked in a disk of radius 10 is the center of the disk?

Tags: probability

I've solved probability problems involving area before, but this was something new. Since points don't have area, I couldn't represent probability as area success/area possible.

Comment: "Since points don't have area, I couldn't represent probability as area success/area possible" Hmmm... "area success" = 0, "area possible" = 100pi, hence "area success/area possible" = ...

Comment: as far as I know the probability of a point of a continuous random variable is zero.

Comment: Think of it this way. What's the odds that you get within $1/1,\!000,\!000$ units of the center? The probability you're looking for is necessarily not greater than that.